# Real Time Push Server for Media

Tags: images, media

I am currently using a real time Push server to push text and small binary data. I am looking for a similar service for Media. Pubnub, which I currently use, limits data transfers to 1.8k, does anyone know of a similar service or setup for larger files?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can be any size. 
Check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193761/how-can-i-send-larger-messages-over-websocket

A better approach might not be to actually push the media, but only push the location of it.  So have your script push the new location of an image, or mp3 or video file, and then have the page (js event) update that item.

This handshake approach might come in useful if you are using static resources hosted on a CDN.